# Update UITableView cells depending on UIPickerView

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, uipickerview

I have an `UIPickerView`

```
-(NSInteger)numberOfComponentsInPickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView     
{     
 return 1;
}

-(NSInteger)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView numberOfRowsInComponent:(NSInteger)component 
{
 return seasons.count;
}

-(void)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView didSelectRow:(NSInteger)row inComponent:(NSInteger)component 
{
 if ([season selectedRowInComponent:0] == 6) {
    matches = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithCapacity: 20];
    [matches insertObject:[NSMutableArray arrayWithObjects:@"aaa", @"bbb", @"1-0", @"15-03-2010", nil] atIndex:0];
 } else if
 .
 .
 .
}
```

Then I have an `UITableView`

```
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
 return matches.count;
}

- (CustomCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{     
 static NSString *simpleTableIdentifier = @"customCell";

 CustomCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:simpleTableIdentifier];

 if (cell == nil) {
    cell = [[CustomCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:simpleTableIdentifier];
 }
 cell.team1.text = matches[indexPath.row][0];
 cell.team2.text = matches[indexPath.row][1];
 cell.score.text = matches[indexPath.row][2];

 return cell;
}
```

So right now the `UITableView` is filled with the objects from the `matches` array that I initialize in my `viewDidLoad`. How can I update the cells content depending on the selected row of the `UIPickerView` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply call `[self.tableView reloadData];` after you update the `matches` array.

```
-(void)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView didSelectRow:(NSInteger)row inComponent:(NSInteger)component 
{
 if ([season selectedRowInComponent:0] == 6) {
    matches = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithCapacity: 20];
    [matches insertObject:[NSMutableArray arrayWithObjects:@"aaa", @"bbb", @"1-0", @"15-03-2010", nil] atIndex:0];
 } else if
 .
 .
 .

 [self.tableView reloadData];
}
```

This assumes that `self` is both the table view data source/delegate and the picker view data source/delegate

Comment: it is working but i got `no index path for table cell being reused`

Comment: Where is this error happening? Are you calling `dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier` any where outside of `cellForRowAtIndexPath`?

Comment: @fabersky, try using `dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:forIndexPath:` instead of just `dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:`.

Comment: @MarcusAdams That's only if you register a class or nib first.

Comment: @MarcusAdams That's fine. You don't need to register a class. The OP's code is fine as-is.

Comment: @rmaddy no I'm not . it's happening when I change the tow of the picker view

Comment: @fabersky Is it crashing your app? Which line of code exactly is causing the crash?

Comment: I declared @property (weak,nonatomic) IBOutlet UITableView *partiteTableView; in the .h and connected my tableView to it in the storyboard as tableView wasn't working. could this cause the issue?

Comment: Then call `reloadData` on `self.partiteTableView`.

Comment: no, it is not crashing. the cells are updating well, but I get this message in the console

Comment: fixed! I had another [tableView beginUpdates] in another method that was causing the issue! thanks!